# Include user headers in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, command-line-tool

I added an additional search path "/opt/local/include" in Build Settings > Search Paths > User Header Search Paths in the default command-line tool project. main.c is not edited. I get a number of Parse Issues with stdio.h with /opt/local/include added. Can we use user headers with Xcode 5 or what is wrong with my setting?

Comment: The problem occurs in Mountain Lion, but does not in Mavericks.

Comment: Have you tried checking 'Always Search User Paths'?